# AST and Parsing in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an assignment and I can't figure out how to define the answer.

#### The assignment

Write the function `exp:: [String] -> (AST, [String])`

`AST`:

- If `x` is a number, it should say `Number x`.
- If it is a "+" og a "-" it should say `Atom x`.
- If it reads a "(", then all the contents behind the "(" until it comes a ")" should be a List `[AST]`.

so that the outputs will be:

```
exp (token "(hi (4) 32)")
> (List [Atom "hi", List [Number 4], Number 32], [])

exp (token "(+ 3 42 654 2)") 
> (List [Atom "+", Number 3, Number 42, Number 654, Number 2], [])

exp (token "(+ 21 444) junk") 
> (List [Atom "+", Number 21, Number 444], ["junk"])
```

#### what I have so far

I already have the token-function, `token :: String -> [String]` which makes a list.

Example:

```
`token "( + 2 ( + 2 3 ) )"
> ["(","+","2","(","+","2","3",")",")"]`
```

The `exp` function looks like this:

```
exp :: [String] -> (AST, [String])
exp [] = error "Empty list"
exp (x:xs)  | x == ")"      = error ""
            | x == "("      = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (List [getAst xs], ss')
            | x == "+"      = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (Atom (read x), ss')
            | x == "-"      = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (Atom (read x), ss')
            | otherwise     = exp xs`
```

where the `getAst` function:

```
getAst :: [String] -> AST
getAst [] = error ""
getAst (x:xs)
            | x == ")"  = error ""
            | x == "("  = (List [getAst xs])
            | isAtom x  = (Atom x) 
            | isNum x   = (Number (read x))
            | otherwise = getAst xs`
```

(And yes, I am a beginner in Haskell..)

Comment: Nice job on the token function. Do you have a start on the `exp` function, or an idea how you'll approach it?

Comment: `exp :: [String] -> (AST, [String])
exp [] = error "Empty list"
exp (x:xs) | x == ")" = error ""
    | x == "(" = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (LList [getAst xs], ss')
    | x == "+" = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (Atom (read x), ss')
    | x == "-" = let (e, ss') = exp xs in (Atom (read x), ss')
    | otherwise = exp xs` 
This is the code i have so far, with a help method called getAst, where i have tried doing [String] -> AST, but not succeeded.

Comment: That is unreadable. Post it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, not used Stackoverflow before. Edited my question now.

Comment: @notgoodinhaskell can you post your `token` function so I can include it in a final solution later?

Answer (score 6):

I think I can try to help you out a bit.

The way the problem is represented you should be able to do this by just looking at the next 
input/token and decide from there where to go.

### some assumptions

The way the data is represented as `[String] -> (Ast, [String])` I assume it's a common parser, where 
a parser tries to read some parts of the input and return the parsed/transformed output together with the rest of the input that it did not transform (so just the two parsts of the tuple - the `Ast` and the rest of the input).

#### the AST type

as you did not include it I assumed it to be:

```
data Ast
  = Number Int
  | Atom String
  | List [Ast]
  deriving Show
```

#### some things I gonna need

I need a few things:

```
import Prelude hiding (exp)

import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust)
```

I have to hide `exp` as we want to use this as a function-name.

Then I want to `fmap` over a `Maybe` so I include the operator from `Control.Applicative`.
This is really just this, in case you did not see it before:

```
f <$> Nothing = Nothing
f <$> Just a  = Just (f a)
```

I want some helpers for `Maybe`:

- `isJust` to check if for `Just _`
- and `fromJust` to get the `a` from `Just a`

Finally I need this helper-function to `read` a bit more safe:

```
tryRead :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
tryRead input =
  case readsPrec 0 input of
    (a,_):_ -> Just a
    _       -> Nothing
```

This will try to read a number here - returing `Just n` if n is a number and `Nothing` otherwise.

### a first go

Here is a **unfinished** first go at your problem:

```
exp :: [String] -> (Ast, [String])
exp (lookat:rest)
  | isJust number = (fromJust number, rest)
  | lookat == "("  = parseList rest []
  where number = Number <$> tryRead lookat

parseList :: [String] -> [Ast] -> (Ast, [String])
parseList inp@(lookat:rest) acc
  | lookat == ")" = (List (reverse acc), rest)
  | otherwise    = let (el, rest') = exp inp
                   in parseList rest' (el:acc)
```

As you can see I just branch based on `lookat` but with a slight twist:

In case I see a number I return the number and the rest-token-list.
In case I see a `(` I start another parser `parseList`.

`parseList` will do the same: 
 - it looks at the first token 
 - if the token is a `)` it finishes the current list (it uses the accumulator technique for this) and returns.
 - if not it uses the existing `exp` parser to get the elements of the list recursively.

Here is an example run:

```
λ> let input = ["(", "2", "(", "3", "4", ")", "5", ")"]

λ> exp input
(List [Number 2,List [Number 3,Number 4],Number 5],[])
```

### TODO

There are some border cases left you have to decide on (what if there are no input tokens?).

And of course you have to add the case for `Atom`s - to finish this excecise.

### full solution

ok - 3 hours later the OP did not check in again so I guess I can post a complete solution.
I hope I did not forget any edge cases and this sureley is not the most efficient implementation (`tokens` comes to mind) - but the examples the OP gave all match:

```
module Ast where

import Prelude hiding (exp)

import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Char (isSpace, isControl)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust)

data Ast
  = Number Int
  | Atom String
  | List [Ast]
  | Empty
  deriving Show

type Token = String

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ parse "(hi (4) 32)"
  print $ parse "(+ 3 42 654 2)"
  print $ parseAst . tokens $ "(+ 21 444) junk"

parse :: String -> Ast
parse = fst . parseAst . tokens

parseAst :: [Token] -> (Ast, [Token])
parseAst [] = (Empty, [])
parseAst (lookat:rest)
  | isJust number = (fromJust number, rest)
  | lookat == "("  = parseList rest []
  | otherwise     = (Atom lookat, rest)
  where number = Number <$> tryRead lookat

parseList :: [Token] -> [Ast] -> (Ast, [Token])
parseList [] _ = error "Syntax error: `)` not found"
parseList inp@(lookat:rest) acc
  | lookat == ")" = (List (reverse acc), rest)
  | otherwise    = let (el, rest') = parseAst inp
                   in parseList rest' (el:acc)
tokens :: String -> [Token]
tokens = split ""
  where split tok "" = add tok []
        split tok (c:cs)
          | c == '(' || c == ')' = add tok $ [c] : split "" cs
          | isSpace c || isControl c = add tok $ split "" cs
          | otherwise = split (tok ++ [c]) cs
        add "" tks = tks
        add t tks =  t : tks

tryRead :: (Read a) => Token -> Maybe a
tryRead input =
  case readsPrec 0 input of
    (a,_):_ -> Just a
    _       -> Nothing
```

#### example run

```
λ> :main
List [Atom "hi",List [Number 4],Number 32]
List [Atom "+",Number 3,Number 42,Number 654,Number 2]
(List [Atom "+",Number 21,Number 444],["junk"])
```

Comment: Instead of `| isJust number = (fromJust number, rest)`, you should used `| Just x <- number = (x, rest)`. Pattern matching is almost always much cleaner than `fromJust`.

Comment: @user2407038 I think that depends - while the pattern matching is nice I think that `isJust number` reads rather well here but if you want just change it for you